# grouping with a cut sequence with floating top and bottom values

Tags: r

I had no idea how to phrase this question, so sorry if the question is a bit confusing.  So I'm creating a function that requires that my PCAR column * my time column is grouped into 100 year blocks based on the cumulative time column. Thanks to this site, I got there using the cut function with group_by to create what I needed. However, I have just realised that its not quite right, the cumulative time is from radiocarbon dates which don't fall exactly on the 100 year blocks, so some of the data I need in the first 100 year block is contained within the second 100 year block. What the code I have is doing is effectivly PCAR[1]*time[1]+PCAR[2]*time[2]+PCAR[3]*time[3] etc where [] references the row of the column.

EDIT (I used the row indexing from excel so I've updated it with row indexing from r)

The problem is, for instance in the first 100 year block final date ends on 99.6, so I need 0.4 more years worth of data in the first group. This group ends on the 29th cell, so to achieve this, the end of the formula for the first group would be PCAR[26]*time[26]+PCAR[27]*0.4 (the difference between the final date and the 100 year cut off). This then means the second group of 100, instead of beginning with PCAR[27]*time[27] needs to be PCAR[27]*(time[27]-0.4) to account for the difference.Group 2 then needs to do the same as group 1 did above, and so on down the column. The gap between the date closest to the 100 year cut off differs randomly as it travels down the column.

I hope that makes sense. I'm afraid I haven't found anything that could help through searching, and to be honest don't really know how to phrase the search terms to find anything relevant.

Sorry to include all of the data but I could't work out how to grab just the first 200 years. I've also only the relevant bit of the function, but this problem gets really out of hand within the rest of the function due to exponentials.

Thanks a lot :)

Function

```
Mega_bog <- function(data) {
  require(tidyverse)
  data %>% mutate(PCAR=((lead(depth.along.core) - depth.along.core )/(lead(Age.cal.BP) - Age.cal.BP))*AFBD*assumed.C*10000,
                  PCA_NCP = PCAR*(lead(Age.cal.BP)-Age.cal.BP), 
                  PCA_NCP[is.na(PCA_NCP)] <- 0, 
                  CCP_Bottom_Up = rev(cumsum(rev(PCA_NCP))),
                  CCP_Top_Down = CCP_Bottom_Up[1]- CCP_Bottom_Up)%>%
                  slice(1:(n()-1))%>%
                  group_by(Century = cut(cumulative.time, breaks = seq(0, max(cumulative.time), 100)))%>%
                  mutate(PCA_NCP_Bin = rev(cumsum(PCAR*time)))%>%
                  group_by(Century) %>% 
                  arrange(desc(PCA_NCP_Bin))%>%
                  slice(1)%>%
                  ungroup()}
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(depth.along.core = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 
5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 
16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 25.5, 26.5, 
27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 
38.5, 39.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 45.5, 46.5, 47.5, 48.5, 
49.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 55.5, 56.5, 57.5, 58.5, 59.5, 
60.5, 61.5, 62.5, 63.5, 64.5, 65.5, 66.5, 67.5, 68.5, 69.5), 
    Age.cal.BP = c(-56.016347625, -55.075825875, -54.201453125, 
    -53.365755375, -52.541258625, -51.700488875, -50.815972125, 
    -49.860234375, -48.805801625, -47.625199875, -46.290955125, 
    -44.775593375, -43.051640625, -41.091622875, -38.868066125, 
    -36.353496375, -33.520439625, -30.341421875, -26.788969125, 
    -22.835607375, -18.453862625, -13.616260875, -8.295328125, 
    -2.463590375, 5.95591868125, 22.32324118125, 43.58107818125, 
    69.41386328125, 99.52472368125, 133.63548018125, 171.48664718125, 
    212.83743268125, 257.46573828125, 305.16815918125, 355.75998418125, 
    409.07519568125, 464.96646968125, 523.30517578125, 583.98137718125, 
    646.90383068125, 711.99998668125, 779.21598918125, 848.51667578125, 
    919.88557768125, 993.32491968125, 1068.85562018125, 1146.51729118125, 
    1226.36823828125, 1308.48546068125, 1392.96465118125, 1479.92019618125, 
    1569.48517568125, 1661.81136328125, 1757.06922618125, 1855.44792518125, 
    1957.15531468125, 2062.41794268124, 2171.48105078125, 2284.60857418125, 
    2402.08314168125, 2524.20607568125, 2651.29739218124, 2783.69580078125, 
    2921.75870468125, 3065.86220068125, 3216.40107918125, 3373.78882418125, 
    3538.45761328125, 3710.85831768125, 3900), time = c(0.94052175, 
    0.87437275, 0.83569775, 0.82449675, 0.84076975, 0.88451675, 
    0.95573775, 1.05443275, 1.18060175, 1.33424475, 1.51536175, 
    1.72395275, 1.96001775, 2.22355675, 2.51456975, 2.83305675, 
    3.17901775, 3.55245275, 3.95336175, 4.38174475, 4.83760175, 
    5.32093275, 5.83173775, 8.41950905625, 16.3673225, 21.257837, 
    25.8327851, 30.1108604, 34.1107565, 37.851167, 41.3507855, 
    44.6283056, 47.7024209, 50.591825, 53.3152115, 55.891274, 
    58.3387061, 60.6762014, 62.9224535, 65.096156, 67.2160025, 
    69.3006866, 71.3689019, 73.439342, 75.5307005, 77.66167099999, 
    79.8509471, 82.1172224, 84.4791905, 86.955545, 89.5649795, 
    92.3261876, 95.2578629, 98.378699, 101.7073895, 105.262628, 
    109.0631081, 113.1275234, 117.4745675, 122.12293400001, 127.09131649999, 
    132.39840860001, 138.0629039, 144.10349600001, 150.5388785, 
    157.387745, 164.6687891, 172.4007044, 189.14168231875, NA
    ), cumulative.time = c(0.94052175, 1.8148945, 2.65059225, 
    3.475089, 4.31585875, 5.2003755, 6.15611325, 7.210546, 8.39114775, 
    9.7253925, 11.24075425, 12.964707, 14.92472475, 17.1482815, 
    19.66285125, 22.495908, 25.67492575, 29.2273785, 33.18074025, 
    37.562485, 42.40008675, 47.7210195, 53.55275725, 61.97226630625, 
    78.33958880625, 99.59742580625, 125.43021090625, 155.54107130625, 
    189.65182780625, 227.50299480625, 268.85378030625, 313.48208590625, 
    361.18450680625, 411.77633180625, 465.09154330625, 520.98281730625, 
    579.32152340625, 639.99772480625, 702.92017830625, 768.01633430625, 
    835.23233680625, 904.53302340625, 975.90192530625, 1049.34126730625, 
    1124.87196780625, 1202.53363880625, 1282.38458590625, 1364.50180830625, 
    1448.98099880625, 1535.93654380625, 1625.50152330625, 1717.82771090625, 
    1813.08557380625, 1911.46427280625, 2013.17166230625, 2118.43429030624, 
    2227.49739840625, 2340.62492180625, 2458.09948930625, 2580.22242330625, 
    2707.31373980624, 2839.71214840625, 2977.77505230625, 3121.87854830625, 
    3272.41742680625, 3429.80517180625, 3594.47396090625, 3766.87466530625, 
    3956.016347625, NA), AFBD = c(0.0711, 0.057, 0.0568, 0.0512, 
    0.0559, 0.0353, 0.0273, 0.0404, 0.0403, 0.0351, 0.0999, 0.0793, 
    0.0852, 0.0702, 0.077, 0.0746, 0.0524, 0.1157, 0.0845, 0.0539, 
    0.1228, 0.0926, 0.1109, 0.1209, 0.106, 0.1031, 0.1118, 0.0894, 
    0.1003, 0.1442, 0.1693, 0.1774, 0.1504, 0.1966, 0.1879, 0.1898, 
    0.1946, 0.1877, 0.1574, 0.1461, 0.1906, 0.1958, 0.187, 0.1793, 
    0.1937, 0.1747, 0.2101, 0.1908, 0.1269, 0.2057, 0.1434, 0.2153, 
    0.2161, 0.223, 0.234, 0.2239, 0.2295, 0.2518, 0.2266, 0.1909, 
    0.2241, 0.1697, 0.2064, 0.2298, 0.186, 0.2076, 0.1714, 0.1579, 
    0.1658, NA), assumed.C = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-70L))
```

EDIT

Expected output:

```
PCAR_Bin <- c(9605.655668,1694.332276,1988.4491,1774.200903,1761.35507,1649.741418,369.141504,
1220.473114,1414.491133,1292.768015,1251.928368,1163.970347,1283.087441,1015.96199,971.2475692,
937.7646391,1072.787868,1139.929522,1133.495179,1148.405794,1074.991721,1054.23838,1096.194291,
1024.730421,887.8396176,801.4013676,881.6495343,658.4457289,705.1585605,758.5538921,797.3435981,
657.1049034,629.3000396,659.5176772,561.8841903,517.0014731,457.9447646,451.4409487,438.2957737)
century <- (1:39)

df1 <- data.frame(PCAR_Bin, century)
```

EDIT: I've added a work around that I'm trying, but failing to get to work in case it helps anyone. I think either I'm going in the wrong direction all together, or it's a maths failure (not my strongest subject) that is stopping me rather than a code failure.
The work around is based on separating columns as Dan suggested giving me the differences I need, and placing them where they need to be. It's then getting the actual output I want that I'm struggling with. The first part of the sum works `PCAR*(Time - the difference)` however, using the lag of the difference means only a single row is multiplied by the difference, rather than the sum of the rows.

```
Mega_bog <- function(data) {
  require(tidyverse)
  data %>% mutate(PCAR=((lead(depth.along.core) - depth.along.core )/(lead(Age.cal.BP) - Age.cal.BP))*AFBD*assumed.C*10000,
                  PCA_NCP = PCAR*(lead(Age.cal.BP)-Age.cal.BP), 
                  PCA_NCP[is.na(PCA_NCP)] <- 0, 
                  CCP_Bottom_Up = rev(cumsum(rev(PCA_NCP))),
                  CCP_Top_Down = CCP_Bottom_Up[1]- CCP_Bottom_Up)%>%
mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0))%>%
    group_by(Century = cut(cumulative.time, breaks = seq(0, max(cumulative.time), 100)))%>%
    separate(Century,c(NA, "time_bin"), sep = ",")%>%
    mutate(time_bin = as.numeric(gsub("]", "", time_bin)),
           dif = time_bin - cumulative.time)%>%
    group_by(time_bin) %>%
    mutate(dif = case_when(dif != min(dif) ~ 0, TRUE ~ dif))%>%
    ungroup()%>%
    mutate(dif1 = lag(dif))}
```

Answer (score 1):

What an interesting problem you had!

There might be a cleaner solution, but here is a workaround centered on `tidyr::separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)

df2 = df %>% 
  mutate(
    PCAR=((lead(depth.along.core)-depth.along.core)/(lead(Age.cal.BP) - Age.cal.BP))*AFBD*assumed.C*10000,
    PCA_NCP = PCAR*(lead(Age.cal.BP)-Age.cal.BP), 
    PCA_NCP[is.na(PCA_NCP)] <- 0, 
    CCP_Bottom_Up = rev(cumsum(rev(PCA_NCP))),
    CCP_Top_Down = CCP_Bottom_Up[1]- CCP_Bottom_Up
  ) %>% 
  select(PCAR, time, cumulative.time) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(PCAR))

df3 = df2 %>% 
  mutate(
    century=ceiling(cumulative.time/100)-1, #same as cut, but outputs a numeric value
    cumulative.time2 = ifelse(!is.na(lag(century)) & century!=lag(century), 
                              paste0(century*100, ";",cumulative.time-century*100), 
                              cumulative.time),
    time2 = ifelse(!is.na(lag(century)) & century!=lag(century), 
                   paste0(century*100-lag(cumulative.time), ";", 
                          time-century*100+lag(cumulative.time)),
                   time),
    PCAR2 = ifelse(!is.na(lag(century)) & century!=lag(century), 
                   paste0(PCAR*(century*100)/cumulative.time, ";", PCAR*(cumulative.time-century*100)/cumulative.time), 
                   PCAR),
  ) %>% 
  separate_rows(time2, cumulative.time2, PCAR2, sep=";") %>% 
  mutate(
    century2=ifelse(!is.na(lag(century)) & century!=lag(century), 
                    century-1, 
                    century), #rescaling century
    across(c(time2, cumulative.time2, PCAR2), as.numeric),
    check=cumsum(time2)
  )
```

First, I calculated centuries as a numeric value with a rounded-up euclidian division. If the century was different than the one of the previous row, I calculated the weighted difference between the current time and the closest century for `PCAR`, `time` (and `cum.time` but useless), then I pasted the 2 values separated by a `;`. This allowed `separate_rows` to split the rows into two children.

Here, row 5 (`cumulative.time==125, PCAR==21.6`) has been separated into rows 5 (`cumulative.time==100`, PCAR==17.2) and 6 (`cumulative.time==25`, PCAR==4.3).

You can check that the sum is the same despite the different number of rows:

```
sum(df2$PCAR)
# [1] 5112.765
sum(df3$PCAR2)
# [1] 5112.765
nrow(df2)
# [1] 69
nrow(df3)
# [1] 103
```

Finally, you can calculate your cumulative sum-product:

```
df3 %>%
  group_by(century2) %>% 
  summarise(result=sum(PCAR2*time2))
#> # A tibble: 40 x 2
#>    century2 result
#>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1        0  9604.
#>  2        1  1233.
#>  3        2  1502.
#>  4        3  1496.
#>  5        4  1515.
#>  6        5  1287.
#>  7        6   786.
#>  8        7  1165.
#>  9        8   931.
#> 10        9  1216.
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

This algorithm is a bit complex and will probably need a lot of checks to verify that it yearned the right results. Still, I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Hi Dan,  Thanks so much for that, really appreciate it. However, I seem to get an error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `time2`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `time2` is `ifelse(...)`.  I'm trying to resolve it, but not getting very far, any ideas?

Comment: @PaulTansley Oops, I forgot to select one column. It works now.

Comment: @ Dan Chaltiel.  Thanks again for your input, it runs fine now. However, I'm afraid the output  off. I've added an edit to my original question that shows the output that I need.

Comment: @Paul could you explain how did you get to `9605.655668` for instance?

Comment: I got the number using an excel formula that looks like: PCAR4*TIME4+PCAR5*TIME5+PCAR6*TIME6+PCAR7*TIME7+PCAR8*TIME8+PCAR9*TIME9+PCAR10*TIME10+PCAR11*TIME11+PCAR12*TIME12+PCAR13*TIME13+PCAR14*TIME14+PCAR15*TIME15+PCAR16*TIME16+PCAR17*TIME17+PCAR18*TIME18+PCAR19*TIME19+PCAR20*TIME20+PCAR21*TIME21+PCAR22*TIME22+PCAR23*TIME23+PCAR24*TIME24+PCAR25*TIME25+PCAR26*TIME26+PCAR27*TIME27+PCAR28*TIME28+PCAR29*TIME29+PCAR30*0.4

Comment: I'm thinking I can achieve it by creating a separate column that is the difference between time_bins and cumulative.time grouping by time bin, and replacing all but the highest and lowest values with 0. Then aligning the columns and performing the sums I need before creating the cumsum. I just need to work out how to replace all but top and bottom values by 0.

Comment: @PaulTansley based on your example, I can see no obvious reason either to start at row 4 or to end at row 29-30. Moreover, `PCAR4` could mean a lot of different things. Your question was well asked at the beginning (hence my +1) but it is getting quite confusing...

Comment: Apologies I've just realised I've been working off the excel indexing in which the data starts on the fourth row, it should be: PCAR[1]*Time[1]+PCAR[2]*Time[2]+PCAR[3]*Time[3]+PCAR[4]*Time[4]+PCAR[5]*Time[5]+PCAR[[6]]*Time[[6]]+PCAR[7]*Time[7]+PCAR[8]*Time[8]+PCAR[9]*Time[9]+PCAR[10]*Time[10]+PCAR[11]*Time[11]+PCAR[12]*Time[12]+PCAR[13]*Time[13]+PCAR[14]*Time[14]+PCAR[15]*Time[15]+PCAR[16]*Time[16]+PCAR[17]*Time[17]+PCAR[18]*Time[18]+PCAR[19]*Time[19]+PCAR[20]*Time[20]+PCAR[21]*Time[21]+PCAR[22]*Time[22]+PCAR[23]*Time[22]+PCAR2[23]*Time[24]+PCAR[25]*Time[25]+PCAR[26]*Time[26]+PCAR[27]*0.4

Comment: @PaulTansley I just have updated my algorithm, `time2` was not calculated right. This is closer to your expected output but still not exactly. I'm not sure which one is correct though

Comment: @Daniel Chaltiel. Thanks, its close to start with but drifts further away from the required output. I've added an edit to show how I've been trying to resolve it.